# Get subscripts from linear index into product of infinite generators

Tags: python, algorithm

I have `N` infinite generators. I already know how to take the Cartesian product of these infinite generators because there are several methods listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099274/python-product-of-infinite-generators) ("zig-zag", "expanding square", etc.). I don't really care which method is used as the basis of what I really want: **I want to convert an "index into the Cartesian product" into a "tuple of indexes into the original generators"** without actually iterating a Cartesian product until that point. I am well aware that I can't actually index into generators. That's fine, because all I need are the indexes themselves. Basically, I want the same thing described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831811/invertable-cartesian-product-elements-index-translation-function) but works for infinite generators.

This will be easiest to understand if we consider a concrete example. Let's consider just two generators (`N=2`) and let them both be `itertools.count()` so that the indexes into the generators and the values of the generators are all the same.

```
from itertools import count
a = count()  # 0, 1, 2, ...
b = count()  # 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Let's assume I use the zig-zag algorithm because the author so kindly made it available on PyPI.

```
from infinite import product
p = product(a, b)  # (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), ...
```

I want a function that, given an index into `p`, returns a tuple of indexes into `a` and `b`, like this:

```
f(2)  # (1,0)
f(4)  # (1,1)
```

Again, it doesn't have to be the linear index into the zig-zag algorithm. Any algorithm that produces the Cartesian product on infinite generators can be used as the basis.

Comment: Still I am not sure why you can create your function `f(n)` to return the value of `n`th index from the result of `product(a, b)` ???

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri `n` could be large and I don't want to iterate over `O(n)` to get an answer that should be calculable directly in `O(1)`

Comment: I'd suggest you try to reduce the amount of information in your question. At the moments it's quite difficult to tell what you're asking. I think your question can be expressed in a single sentence: _"Given an index `n` as input, how can I calculate the nth element in the sequence `[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(1,1),(2,0),...]`?"_

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to invert a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function). The "zig-zag" algorithm you give as an example is the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) (up to a change of argument order), given by `f(x, y) = (x+y)(x+y+1)/2 + y`, and it has inverse as follows.

If `f^-1(z) = (x, y)`, then

```
w = floor((sqrt(8z+1)-1)/2)
t = w(w+1)/2
y = z-t
x = w-y
```

You can see the Wikipedia links for the full derivation.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for in two dimensions. If I can figure out how to extend it to arbitrary dimensions, I'll post it as a new answer.

Comment: @drhagen: You can "unpair" the results of unpairing to generate 3-tuples and beyond, although the order won't be anything like `infinite.product`.

Answer (score 0):

The various methods of generating the Cartesian products are all variants of the same procedure:

1. Partition the product tuples into a countably infinite number of finite-sized chunks;
2. Generate the tuples in each chunk in turn.

The "zigzag" method and Cantor's function, for example, chunk by the sum of indexes:

```
For integer i = 0 to infinity
    generate all tuples with sum(component_indexes) == i
```

The "expanding square method" is:

```
For integer i = 0 to infinity
    generate all tuples with max(component_indexes) == i
```

etc...

To find the kth tuple directly for any of these methods, you:

1. Let **SMALLER(i)**  be the number of tuples in chunks numbered less than **i**.  Find the maximum **i** such that **SMALLER(i) <= k**.  This is the number of the chunk that contains the **kth** tuple.
2. Get the **(k-SMALLER(i))th** tuple (zero-based) with in chunk number **i**.

For the "expanding square" method in **N** dimensions, for example, **SMALLER(i) = i^N** -- the number of tuples with all components less than **i**, so **i = floor(Nth_root(k))**.  Let **r = k - i^N**, and then find the **rth** tuple (in lexical order, for example) with max component equal to **k**.

The *easiest* kind of product to index directly, though, is *bit interleaving*.  In this scheme, successive bits in the binary expansion of the product index are assigned to the component indexes in round-robin fashion.  In python it looks like this:

```
def getProductTerm(dimensions, index):
    ret=[0]*dimensions
    bit=0
    while index>0:
        ret[dimensions-1-(bit%dimensions)]+=(index&1)<<(bit/dimensions)
        index >>= 1
        bit+=1
    return ret
```

You can try it here: https://ideone.com/0dTMU3